# In Corda, can the output of one transaction be used by new transaction in the same flow?

Tags: kotlin, corda

There is a flow as per below scenario. 
Transaction 1: Input StateA - ContractA results in output StateB - ContractA 
Transaction 2: Input StateB - ContractA and no output 
Is this possible in Corda?
Please do share an example with response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. For example:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class TwoTransactionFlow(val inputStateAndRefA: StateAndRef<StateA>) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

        // Creating, signing and finalising the first transaction.
        val txBuilderOne = TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addInputState(inputStateAndRefA)
                .addOutputState(StateB(), ContractA.ID)
                .addCommand(ContractA.Commands.Transfer(), ourIdentity.owningKey)

        val signedTxOne = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilderOne)
        val notarisedTxOne = subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTxOne))

        // Creating, signing and finalising the second transaction.
        val stateRefB = StateRef(notarisedTxOne.id, 0)
        val stateAndRefB = serviceHub.toStateAndRef<StateB>(stateRefB)

        val transactionBuilderTwo = TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addInputState(stateAndRefB)
                .addCommand(ContractA.Commands.Exit(), ourIdentity.owningKey)

        val signedTransactionTwo = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilderTwo)
        subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTransactionTwo))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this helps. Also, if we have multiple signers i.e. how does it work with CollectSignaturesFlow?

Comment: No problem. Could you raise a separate question please?

Comment: Thanks. I've raised a separate question, here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983150/in-corda-can-the-output-of-one-transaction-be-used-in-the-same-flow-with-multip