# Corda: Can the output of one transaction be used in another transaction within the same flow with multiple same signers?

Tags: kotlin, corda

There is a flow as per below scenario.
Initiating Party : PartyA 
Responding Party : PartyB 
Transaction 1: Input StateA - ContractA results in output StateB - ContractA. Participants are PartyA and PartyB 
Transaction 2: Input StateB - ContractA and no output. Participants are PartyA and PartyB 
Is this possible in Corda? Please do share an example with response. Thanks.

Comment: What issue are you encountering when you try and do this as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929072/in-corda-can-the-output-of-one-transaction-be-used-by-new-transaction-in-the-sa?

Comment: The error i get is the session has been completed with the other party. Also, i tried to initiate a new session with the party but i get the error we cannot initiate multiple sessions with the same party from the same initiating flow.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you rephrase the question title and question? It's not really about using the output of one transaction in the same flow, but rather about collecting signatures from the same counterparty twice in one flow.

Comment: Updated the question, but is this possible with corda-3.2?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're getting two different error messages:

- If you don't try and initiate a second flow-session to get the second signature, you get something like:

  > net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Counterparty flow on
  >   O=Mock Company 2, L=London, C=GB has completed without sending data
- While if you do initiate a second flow-session to get the second signature, you get something like:

  > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to initiateFlow() twice in
  >   the same InitiatingFlow
  >   com.example.flow.ExampleFlow$Initiator@312d7fe4 for the same party
  >   O=Mock Company 2, L=London, C=GB. This isn't supported in this version
  >   of Corda. Alternatively you may initiate a new flow by calling
  >   initiateFlow() in an @InitiatingFlow sub-flow.

In the first case, the error is caused by the fact that the counterparty's flow has already completed. You try and get around this by creating a second flow session, but each `Initiating` flow can only initiate a single flow-session with a given counterparty.

Instead, you simply need to modify the responder flow to sign twice. For example:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Acceptor(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartyFlow) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                // Transaction checks...
            }
        }

        subFlow(signTransactionFlow)
        subFlow(signTransactionFlow)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible .Please find the link to know more

https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-transactions.html